# Running Jbehave from Ant build file

Tags: selenium-webdriver, ant, testng, jbehave

I am trying to run the jbehave stories from Ant build.xml file.
I have testng framework. I am able to execute tests in below ways

-jbehave tests from testng.xml and
-usual classes with @Test tag from build.xml.

Problem is when I integrate above two steps i.e., add the Jbehave config class (which get the stories)in the testng.xml file and try to trigger from build.xml.

I see in console in below way.
......
BeforeStories
AfterStories 
........

But the actual execution is getting skipped.

Anyhelp is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in bin folder, whether stories folder is present or not. 
Note :In ant build while compile class file, story file will not be compiled to bin folder, need to copy the story folder to bin folder.

```
<copy todir ="bin/storiespackage">
<fileset dir="src/storiespackage"/>
</copy>
```

Hope this will work.